# Correlate bivariate Brownian bridges

Tags: r, correlation, interpolation

Given two independently constructed [Brownian bridges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge) (from their marginal means and variances), is there a way to correlate the sample paths?

Comment: hmm can we consider bridges that are pinned to non-zero locations? Also are the bridges pinned at the same time $t$?  If it is as you have linked, where they are constrained to (1,0), then simply:
$$cBB^1_t = BB^1_t$$ and
$$cBB^2_t = \rho BB^1_t + \sqrt{ 1- \rho^2 }BB^2_t $$
should work.

Comment: Thanks. So in general to construct the multivariate Brownian bridge from the one-dimensional (based on each marginal), one just need to  multiply them by the square root of the variance-covariance matrix?

Comment: Yup, that should do it.